# Calculating an integration with exp in the power of exp

Tags: calculus, integration

I wanted to know if  there is any efficient way to deal with integrals like this

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(a\mathbf ix + b\exp\left(-x^2\right)\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $\mathbf i$ is an imaginary number. I have tried a change of variable and integration by parts, could not get anywhere so far. I have found the series representation of the solution, but I was looking for an analytical kind of solution, as it is supposed to be a distribution function, after being multiplied with a suitable constant at the end. Many thanks for any hints that I can get here.

Mathematic gives the following result:

$$\begin{align}&\exp(b)x + \dfrac12\mathbf ia\exp(b)x^2 - \dfrac16x^3\left(\exp(b)\left(a^2 + 2b\right)\right) \\ &- \dfrac1{24}\mathbf ia\exp(b)x^4\left(a^2 + 6b\right) + \dfrac1{120}\exp(b)x^5\left(a^4 + 12a^2b + 12b(b + 1)\right) \\ &+ \dfrac1{720}\mathbf ia\exp(b)x^6\left(a^4 + 20a^2b + 60b(b + 1)\right) \\ &- \dfrac{x^7\left(\exp(b)\left(a^6 + 30a^4b + 180a^2b(b + 1) + 120b\left(b^2 + 3b + 1\right)\right)\right)}{5040} + \mathcal O\left(x^8\right) + \mathrm{constant}\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you maybe give us the series you got

Comment: @kepler why did you rollback the edit? Writing mathematical expressions in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is preferable since it allows for [efficient (math) searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: I wanted to add the series that I got from Mathematica.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the mathematical expressions.

Comment: Easy.  The integral diverges.

Comment: But Mathematica presented a series representation as I added to the question.

Comment: That integral of course not depend on $x$, but your Mathematica output does.  Perhaps you asked Mathematica the wrong question.

Comment: Perhaps the input to Mathematica was an _indefinite_ version of the integral

Comment: I gave it option on this, I guess you are right on taking the indefinite version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral diverges.

Example, $a=b=1$.  Here is $\mathrm{Re}\;\int_{-T}^T 
\exp\left(ix + \exp\left(-x^2\right)\right)\;dx$
[image: A]

We can guess from this that the limit $T \to +\infty$ does not exist.

---

More rigorously:  Assume $a,b > 0$.

Integrate by parts.  $C(T) = C_1(T)+C_2(T)$, where
$$
C(T) = \int_{-T}^T\exp(aix) \exp\left(b\exp\left(-x^2\right)\right)\;dx
\\
C_1(T) = {\frac {-i{{\rm e}^{b{{\rm e}^{-{T}^{2}}}}}{{\rm e}^{aTi}}}{a}}+{
\frac {i{{\rm e}^{b{{\rm e}^{-{T}^{2}}}}}{{\rm e}^{-iaT}}}{a}}
\\
C_2(T) = -\int_{-
T}^{T}\!{\frac {2\,ibx{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}}}{{\rm e}^{b{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2
}}}}}{{\rm e}^{iax}}}{a}}\;dx
$$

First consider$$
C_1(T) = \frac{2}{a}\exp\left(b\exp(-T^2)\right)\sin(aT)
$$
It does not converge as $T \to +\infty$.  Indeed, along these two sequences it has different limits:
$$
C_1\left(\frac{(4n-1)\pi}{2a}\right)
= -\frac{2}{a}\exp\left(b\exp(-T^2)\right)
\to -\frac{2}{a} ,
\\
C_1\left(\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2a}\right)
= \frac{2}{a}\exp\left(b\exp(-T^2)\right)
\to \frac{2}{a} .
$$
Next consider $C_2(T)$.  This integral converges.  Indeed
$$
\int_{-
\infty}^{\infty}\!\left|{\frac {2\,ibx{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}}}{{\rm e}^{b{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2
}}}}}{{\rm e}^{iax}}}{a}}\right|\;dx \le
2\int_{0}^\infty\frac{2b}{a} x e^{-x^2}\;dx = \frac{2b}{a} < \infty .
$$

So we conclude $\lim_{T\to\infty} C_1(T)$ does not converge,
$\lim_{T\to\infty} C_2(T)$ converges,
and therefore that their sum $\lim_{T\to\infty} C(T)$ does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and detailed answer. It was part of calculating the inverse transform of that function. So I shall conclude that the whole partial differential equation does not have an answer.